# openui5 event Handler for orientationchange

Tags: screen-orientation, sapui5, window-resize

Is there any openui5 event Handler for orientationchange and window resize ?

```
onInit: function() {
    var data;
    this.drawChart(data);    // working fine
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        this.drawChart(data);    // not working
    });
},

drawChart: function(data) {
    //code for draw chart
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenUI5 has built-in functionality for detecting orientation change as well as when there is a responsive size change (desktop->tablet for example).

Take a look at [sap.ui.Device.orientation's](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.Device.orientation.html) `attachHandler` event:

> Registers the given event handler to orientation change events of the
>   document's window.

Here is an example of using `sap.ui.Device.orientation.attachHandler`:

```
sap.ui.Device.orientation.attachHandler(function(mParams) {
    if (mParams.landscape) {
        alert('in landscape mode');
    } else {
        alert('in portrait mode');
    }
});
```

Also of use is [sap.ui.Device.media](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.Device.media.html)'s `attachHandler` for detecting when the window is resized to a different [range-set](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.Device.media.RANGESETS.html).

For directly listening to when the window is resized it looks like you already have a solution for that, just make sure you keep track of the correct scope to use:

```
var self = this;
$( window ).resize(function() {
    self.drawChart(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

this.* will not work inside jquery as this has a different meaning wherever its encapsulated...
in openui5 *.view.js this implies the view object
 in *.controller.js this implies the controller object...
in jquery this implies the component in which it is placed or whatever it is referring to in that context...
 you cannot simply mix "this" wherever you like

sap.ui.controller("oui5mvc.controllerName").drawChart(data);

Comment: This "this" behavior is not specific to jQuery or OpenUI5. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. There are even [40-minute courses](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/) teaching only this keyword...